Seeing the follow questions popup on sites I have more than 15 rep
When the follow questions/answers feature was rolled out, it included a popup notifying users about it. There was a feature request asking for it to be globally dismissible, and Yaakov Ellis mentioned in the comments later that a feature was implemented so that users with ≥15 rep would not see the popup.
However, recently I have been encountering this popup again on multiple sites. It seems to appear on sites where I have the association bonus, but have not earned 15 rep otherwise. EG: I see this on ServerFault where I have 101 rep.
Could this be fixed to correctly not show for users with the association bonus, as it is quite annoying have to manually dismiss it on many, many sites I visit only to help flag spam or other inappropriate posts across the network.

Blatant speculation: I wonder if it's actually coded as 15 reputation earned on that specific site, like the remove-new-user-restrictions privilege (which it shouldn't be, because it's a question of whether you know the thing exists, and if you're assumed to know it exists with 15 rep, surely having enough to get the association bonus elsewhere ought to count).
